# array value appears as undefined javasctript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, undefined

my array values appears as undefined in the console log and it also appears as undefined when I called it in the text. the beverage array and cart array wont display the values only undefiend

javascript

```
let beverages = [{
    name: 'espresso',
    price: 1.95
},
{
    name: 'latte',
    price: 2.95
},
{
    name: 'cappuccino',
    price: 3.45
},
{
    name: 'coffee',
    price: 1.75
},
{
    name: 'biscotti',
    price: 1.95
},
{
    name: 'scone',
    price: 2.95
}
  ]

let cart = [];

let sum = 0;


function add_to_cart(item) {

let qty = prompt('Please enter quantity ')
qty = parseInt(qty);
if (isNaN(qty)) {
    qty = 1
}

cart.push({
    name: item,
    quantity: qty
});
document.getElementById("order").textContent = cart
console.log(beverages.name)
}
```

Comment: it appears `beverages` is not defined anywhere? maybe you're mistaking `beverages` for `cart`? Or maybe the item you're pushing into cart you mean to define as var beverages

Comment: nah...bevarages in defined in an array i didnt include...i included now

Comment: beverages is an array, not an object. So if you want to access `name`, you'll need to provide the index within the array that you want to get the name for.. like `beverages[0].name`

Comment: so do i have to loop through it

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you want to see all beverage names?

Comment: nevermind i got it i loop through the cart array to assign the object in the cart to the object in the beverages...thanks for the help